# How do I initialize an SVG layer using leaflet in typescript?

Tags: javascript, .net, svg, typescript, leaflet

I'm following this example and trying to convert it to typescript, but I am unable to call the _initPathRoot function to initialize an SVG layer on the map. It works in plain javascript, but not in typescript.

Here is the offending line of code:

```
// initialize the SVG layer
map._initPathRoot()
```

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a documented method (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html). We try not to add *non-standard* non-documented methods to the TypeScript definitions. However you can always use them by being *explicitly* type unsafe:

```
// initialize the SVG layer
map['_initPathRoot']()
```